# throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongojs

I have created an express application with MongoJS. I am returning a function, still it's showing an object has been returned. I have even added `module.exports=router` in my JavaScript page. Can someone please point out the missing export here?

`app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var define = require('./user/userSlots');
var app = express();
app.set("views", "./view");
app.use('/', define);
app.listen(3111, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3111!');
});
```

`userSlots.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var module = require('../admin/dbModule');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/login', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.params.username;
    var email = request.params.email;
    module.authenticateUser(username, email, response);
});
module.exports = router;
```

`dbModule.js`:

```
var mongojs = require("../../node_modules/mongojs");
var databaseUrl = "localhost/user";
var db = mongojs(databaseUrl);
var test = db.collection('user_information');
var message = null;
db.user_information.ensureIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true });
exports.authenticateUser = function(username, email, response) {
    db.user_information.find({ username: username, email: email }, function(err, users) {
        if (err || !users) {
            console.log("Failure");
            message = "Failure";
            reponse.render('index', { title: 'Hello', message: message });
        } else if (users.length == 0) {
            console.log("Not Valid user");
            message = "Failure";
            reponse.render('index', { title: 'Hello', message: message });
        } else {
            console.log("valid");
            message = "Success";
            reponse.render('index', { title: 'Hello', message: message });
        }
    });
}
```

Error:

```
E:\Vehicles\vehicles.com\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458

      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a '
 + gettype(fn));
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (E:\Vehicles\vehicles.com\node_modules\express\li
b\router\index.js:458:13)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (E:\Vehicles\vehicles.com\node_module
s\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at EventEmitter.use (E:\Vehicles\vehicles.com\node_modules\expres
s\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Vehicles\vehicles.com\application\app.j
s:12:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are causing a problem by redefining `module` in this line:

```
var module = require('../admin/dbModule');
```

And, then expecting it to be the original, built-in `module` later with this:

```
module.exports = router;
```

Change this:

```
var module = require('../admin/dbModule');
```

to a different name:

```
var dbModule = require('../admin/dbModule');
```

And, then use `dbModule` to refer to your database module and then the built-in `module` will still be available for normal use in `module.exports`.